# R Function Troubleshooting : converting hist() interval counts into percentile frequencies

Tags: r, matrix, histogram, apply

I'm working with a large matrix of 1,000 simulations of nearly 100,000 events. The outputs are ratios. I'd like to avoid using a loop if I can, because I don't know if my computer would be able to handle it, so I'm trying to construct a function which uses hist() to convert the ratios of each simulation into counts, and then in turn convert these counts into frequencies. I've been able to apply the steps inside of the function to the matrix as a whole, but struggle on how to apply these steps to each simulation and generate results as output.

```
function <- function(my_data) {
# Create intervals
intervals <- seq(0,1, by = .01)
# Create histogram
H <- hist(
          my_data, plot = FALSE,
          breaks = intervals, 
          right = FALSE,
          na.rm = TRUE) 
# Convert 
out <- H$counts/dim(my_data)[1]
return(out)
}

percentile_freqs <- apply(x, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function)

#Error message (the same printed thousands of times)
#1: In hist.default(my_data, plot = FALSE, breaks = func_intervals,  ... :
 #argument ‘...’ is not made use of

class(percentile_freqs)
#[1] "numeric"

dim(percentile_freqs)
#NULL
```

Comment: Aha. Well, I in fact don't have function isn't the actual object name, but I clearly overlooked what you've pointed out in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've stumbled upon the solution. As user Jean-Claude Arbaut commented, I can't assign to a keyword, although this keyword wasn't in my original code (sorry about that). Anyway, I don't have a real explanation, but the code below seems to work!

```
Funct <- function(my_data) {
# Create intervals
intervals <- seq(0,1, by = .01)
# Create histogram
H <- hist(
          my_data, plot = FALSE,
          breaks = intervals, 
          right = FALSE
         ) 
# Convert 
out <- H$counts/(sum(H$counts))
return(out)
}
```

I've only made two changes. First, at the #Convert stage, changing the devisor from dim(my_data)[1] to (sum(H$counts)). Also removed the na.RM argument in hist(), although I'm certain this wasn't necessary.